# Magento 1.9 Newly created Bundle Products missing in Catalog_Product_Index_Price

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, indexing

This is involved. When I reindex all products but newly created products show up in catalog_product_index_price table (i'm mentioning this one given it does include cataloginventory_stock_status_idx and all other index tables). New products are showing in cataloginventory_stock_status_idx but the stock status is set to 1 *(all other products that are working have a stock status of 0)*.

**1. What is the cataloginventory stock status value suppose to tell me?**

There are no errors when I reindex any of the indexes. Also if i try something like:

```
$_category->getProductCount();
```

On the category related to these newly created bundle products it returns 0. This is related because the actual, *getProductCount()*, function is pulling from an index collection. I don't totally think its the indexing given that the catalog is indexed correctly. It seems like it is happening to new products only.

**2. Conceptually, what could cause a BUNDLE product from being indexed? What Should I look for?**

*Would greatly appreciate Short, sweet and to-the-point responses.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused my missing Price type attribute, not sure why though. There was no link in the catalog_product_entity_int for the product and attribute. I created a shell script (placed in /shell directory) that

```
1. Found all active bundle products that did not have a price type

2. Foreach through the collection and ->setPRiceType(0) and saved products
```

After so, reindexed everything and all was good. New bundles actually DID have the attr set. This issue was from older bundles.

Comment: Is anyone else having this issue? I just updated to 1.9.3.6 from 1.9.3.2 and I had to manually change the *existing* bundles from `price_type = NULL` to `price_type = 0`. New bundles work fine. It's the existing bundles that disappear from the category list view due to not having entries in the table `catalog_category_product_index` (due to attribute `price_type=NULL` in `catalog_product_entity_int` -- I don't know why and frustratingly I can't find the code change responsible for it)

Comment: The same issue I am facing in Enterprise edition. Hopefully, this will help.